# how to print session data?

Tags: php, session

read some data from xml file and store it in session.i had start session in very first line of my php file and here is my code of storing session.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("agent.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            $agent = $xml->xpath("//agent[id=1]");
            if (!empty($agent)) 
            {
                $item = $agent[0];
                 $_SESSION['name'] = $item->name;
                 $_SESSION['image'] = $item->image;
                 $_SESSION['company'] = $item->company;
                 $_SESSION['street'] = $item->street;
                 $_SESSION['city'] = $item->city;
                 $_SESSION['phone'] = $item->phone;
```

and i am displaying this data by following code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    echo "your session is runnung";
 }
 else{
    echo "Sorry";
 }
?>
```

But this is not working please guys suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: Define `this is not working`.

Comment: did you try `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: Check seesion using print_r();
Example :    
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>";
Try it.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION); prints array(0) { }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the values are stored in the $_SESSION array, which we access here. Another way to show this is to simply run this code:

```
 <?php 
 session_start(); 
 print_r ($_SESSION);
 ?>
```

Comment: that prints Array ( )

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
 session_start(); 
 print_r ($_SESSION);
 echo "<p>";

 //This help to print single entry from the array
 echo $_SESSION['name'][0];
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

did u try

`var_dump($_SESSION);`

or

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: yes but that prints blank array()

Comment: i think your `$xml = simplexml_load_file("agent.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            $agent = $xml->xpath("//agent[id=1]");` code not working.

Comment: check your xml file and tags are in it